# Extrapolating a 2D vector field in four dimensions

Tags: multiple-regression, vector-fields

I'm not really sure how to explain this, but I've got several 2D vectors located at points in 4-space and I want to generate a continuous approximation(?) of this. My data looks like this:

```
|  x  |  y  |  z  |  t  |  vx  |  vy  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
| 1.3 | 3.5 | 4.1 | 0.0 |  2.4 | -0.1 |
| 1.6 | 3.3 | 4.0 | 1.2 |  1.3 |  0.4 |
| 1.4 | 3.2 | 4.3 | 1.5 |  1.1 |  0.3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  ... |  ... |
```

That's three spatial coordinates, a unique time coordinate, and two vectors on a plane perpendicular to the $z$ axis. $t$ strictly increases, and $z = e(x, y)$ (which looks like 2D pink noise). $\frac{dz}{dt}$ is approximately constant for high values of $dz$; for low values of $dz$, $\frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{dt}$ is approximately constant. The vector field is chaotic, continuous and slowly evolves over $t$; the data is just samples of it.

I'd like to generate a continuous function $f(x, y, z, t) \rightarrow \vec{v}$, but I have no idea what regression algorithm to use or really where to start with this. You can assume that I've already cleaned up the data, so that the points are very very close to the correct values.

Comment: do you want $f$  to be linear or affine or something?

Comment: That's pretty broad...do you have any other information that could narrow things down? For example: 1) Is the relationship between $x,y,z$ and $v_x, v_y$ fixed, or does it change over time? 2) Do $v_x, v_y$ only depend on the current $x,y,z$, or does history matter? 3) Do you know anything about the nature of the function? E.g. is it linear or nonlinear? If nonlinear, does it have some particular form?

Comment: @user20160 1) It changes over time; otherwise I would be discarding $t$. 2) I don't understand the question. 3) No.

Comment: It would take a large book to answer this question.  An instance of what is needed is Wikle and Cressie, *Statistics for Spatio-Temporal Data* (2011), 523 pages.